# Scaling canvas and keeping center

Tags: android, canvas

I'm want to scale a canvas with a bitmap drawn on it. I'm able to scale the canvas but the bitmap drawn on it moves to the upper left respectively lower right.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

    //draw bitmap
}
```

For the last few days I tried many different approaches from manipulating translation coordinates to pivot points for scaling. But nothing did work for me. I'm pretty sure there must be an easy solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly do you want the bitmap to scale? What does this mean: "but the bitmap drawn on it moves to the upper left respectively lower right."

Comment: Lets say I have a red circle in the center of the screen. If I zoom in I want to have a bigger red circle in the center of the screen. Right now I get a bigger red circle that is in the bottom right corner of the screen

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like you mentioned, the pivot point is the correct way to do this:

```
canvas.scale(2,2, redCircle.x, redCircle.y);
```

will work. There is no need for extra translation.

Comment: The red circle was only an example. In fact there are many different bitmaps drawn on the canvas. I want to zoom on whats ever in the center of the screen.

Comment: Then your pivot point should be the center of your screen. If you've already tried that, you must have been using incorrect values for the centerX and centerY.

Comment: Okay. Now I can zoom to the center of the screen. But now the scrolling on the canvas is really slow `canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
   canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);`

Comment: That's probably the correct behavior, although I haven't checked. Try multiplying your translate amounts by the mScaleFactor.

Answer (score 1):

```
var widthNew = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
var heightNew = ctx.canvas.height / 2;
ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,-(scale-1)*widthNew,-(scale-1)*heightNew);
```

This will help you scale the canvas horizontally and vertically with the horizontal and vertical translation.