# How to prevent a custom view from moving when scaling on Android?

Tags: java, android, scale, android-custom-view

I am implementing scaling functionality inside a custom view on Android, based on the tutorial from [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/gestures/scale#basic-scaling-example). The scaling feature seems to be working fine, but I am facing an issue where the view moves to the origin (0, 0) when I scale down. I want the view to remain in its original position while scaling.

Here's the code for my custom view:

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;

    private Paint paint;

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float cx = getWidth()/2f;
        float cy = getHeight()/2f;

        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

        canvas.drawRect(cx - 100, cy - 100, cx + 100, cy + 100, paint);

        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener
            extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Currently, when I scale down, the rectangle moves to the point (0, 0), instead of remaining at the center of the screen. I want to fix this issue and ensure that the view stays in its original position. How can I do this?

I have attached a GIF that shows the issue:

[image]

Comment: I guess that's because you are scaling the whole Canvas, doing so it shrinks towards origin 0,0. You can solve the problem setting the parent's gravity (I'm not too sure about this solution, I haven't checked yet) to center, or apply the scale only on the draws and not on the entire Canvas

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Mirco0. I believe the solution to the issue in question would be to use `canvas.translate(dx, dy)` to return the view to its original position. However, I'm unsure about how to calculate the necessary values for `dx` and `dy`. It's possible that we may need to use a mathematical formula to determine the amount of displacement required. Do you have any insights on this?

Comment: I searched up a bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854397/scaling-canvas-and-keeping-center), I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Mirco0. Your suggestion was helpful! I added the following line of code `canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, cx, cy);` and that solved the problem. Can you please elaborate an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's because you are scaling the whole Canvas, doing so it shrinks towards origin (0,0).

`canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);`

You can solve this setting a pivot to the scale, like this as we discussed in the comments

`canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, cx, cy);`